# Notify search engines on 404 pages

Tags: search-engine-indexing, sitemap, google-index, 404

How to pro-actively notify search engines (Google and others) of removed pages 404s that are still indexed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML sitemap is usually the best method to pro-actively notify search engines of anything, not just 404 pages. But I fail to understand why you would want to do that? Having 404 pages in Google's index isn't necessarily a bad thing, unless of course these 404 pages are still getting a lot of search hits, in which case you may want to 301 redirect them to some other relevant page. Google usually waits 24 hours before removing a 404 page from its index, but if you want to expedite the process I would suggest returning a 410 status code instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've edited out the signature line as per [the Webmasters SE guidelines](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

Comment: @Nina Thank you for the response. We need this for developing an app. So as you have described when we add the 404 pages to an XML and submit it, it will get removed from Google, right?

Comment: @Jenz glad to help here. Yes, by submitting a sitemap of your 404 pages to Google you can expedite the removal process, in fact this is something that Google recommends. https://www.seroundtable.com/404-sitemaps-google-removal-26926.html. But do this as a temporary measure. Remove the sitemap after your 404 pages are de-indexed.

Comment: @NinaDubovich Once we submit sitemap with 404 will the pages get removed from Google fastly?

Comment: Yes, it will certainly "expedite" the process.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in other answers you can handle this issue with help of header status.

If you are still in real hurry and want it removed as fast as possible then you can use remove urls from your Google Webmaster Tools >> Search Console.

Usually it is advisable to allow it to get drop by itself but this is when your 404 page is hurting your rankings or business somehow.